# Lucene query for string containing # (hash symbol)

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

How to query an elastic search index using Lucene for strings containing special characters such as @ and # for example "@company.com" or "#rescheduled" i.e. it has to have the # in front of the word and not just the word itself, currently getting:

[image]

Tried all sorts of escape combinations but no luck. Although reading [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) does not indicate # or @ are special characters that need escaping

examples of what I've tried. field is called comments:

```
comments:#rescheduled
comments:"#rescheduled"
comments:\#rescheduled
comments:\"#rescheduled\"
comments:\"\#rescheduled\"
```

There is no error, it just returns docs which contain both "#rescheduled" and "rescheduled"

Comment: Image upload not working

Comment: If you are getting an error, you should provide the full contents of that error as text, not as an image. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) for some reasons why.

Comment: "_all sorts of escape combinations_" - You should show us what you already tried. This will help the community to avoid spending time trying something you already know does not work. You should also provide a [mre] to help the community recreate the problem. This should include details of how the data was originally indexed, in case the indexing analyzer is related to your problem.

Comment: @andrewJames added more detail

Comment: Thank you for the updates. You should also provide a [mre] to help the community recreate the problem. This should include details of how the data was originally indexed, in case the indexing analyzer is related to your problem.

Comment: (And I think you can fix that "_currently getting..._" part of the question, also. If the image you tried to upload contains text then you can [provide the text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).)